# Aquamacs compiling shortcut

Tags: aquamacs

Is there a way to make a shortcut key only by which I can compile a `.tex` file?

For LaTeX compilation, I'm using shortcut `^C ^C`. It shows me 'latex' as default or 'view' sometimes. If it is set to 'latex', I just press Enter but set to 'view', then I have to type 'latex' to compile. Then I use `^C ^V`to view the `pdf` if needed.

This is the most frequent operation that I use but it's quite annoying to type 'latex' explicitly after `^C ^C`. I'm a novice on Emacs and Aquamacs (have used it just for a week).

Comment: You can create a keyboard macro, save it, and then bind it to a key.  (I can't find the specific function, either, but it could be `trace`d.)

Comment: Hint: you can just type `l` and press enter.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just click on the LaTeX button in the tool bar. :)

[image]

Alternatively, do Command-O to open a file and navigate to

```
<HOME>/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs
```

and open `Preferences.el` (which is preferred in Aquamacs to the `.emacs` file). Add at the bottom

```
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
  (local-set-key
  (kbd "C-c c")
   (lambda nil
    (interactive)
    (progn
     (TeX-save-document
      (TeX-master-file)
     )
    (TeX-command "LaTeX" (quote TeX-master-file) -1))))))
```

that will bind the same function executed by clicking the icon  to `C-c c`. You might want to add a similar action bound to `C-c v` for viewing

```
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
  (local-set-key
  (kbd "C-c v")
  (lambda nil (interactive)
   (TeX-command "View" (quote TeX-master-file) -1)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Aquamacs and had the same question. The post from Sean Allred helped me find the answer I was looking for. The only thing I would add is that if you solely use Aquamacs it is better to edit the file

```
 Preference.el
```

located in

```
 ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs\ Emacs/
```

Once you add the code below in the file the command sequence

```
 C-c C-a
```

will run the default compiler and then send the output to preview. This snippet of code was copied from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TN#toc8 under the TEX-texify section.

```
    (require 'tex-buf)
(defun TeX-command-default (name)
  "Next TeX command to use. Most of the code is stolen from `TeX-command-query'."
  (cond ((if (string-equal name TeX-region)
                 (TeX-check-files (concat name "." (TeX-output-extension))
                          (list name)
                          TeX-file-extensions)
               (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file)))
             TeX-command-default)
            ((and (memq major-mode '(doctex-mode latex-mode))
                  (TeX-check-files (concat name ".bbl")
                           (mapcar 'car
                               (LaTeX-bibliography-list))
                           BibTeX-file-extensions))
             ;; We should check for bst files here as well.
             TeX-command-BibTeX)
            ((TeX-process-get-variable name
                           'TeX-command-next
                           TeX-command-Show))
            (TeX-command-Show)))


(defcustom TeX-texify-Show t "Start view-command at end of TeX-texify?" :type 'boolean :group 'TeX-command)
(defcustom TeX-texify-max-runs-same-command 5 "Maximal run number of the same command" :type 'integer :group 'TeX-command)

(defun TeX-texify-sentinel (&optional proc sentinel)
  "Non-interactive! Call the standard-sentinel of the current LaTeX-process.
If there is still something left do do start the next latex-command."
  (set-buffer (process-buffer proc))
  (funcall TeX-texify-sentinel proc sentinel)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (when (string-match "\\(finished\\|exited\\)" sentinel)
      (set-buffer TeX-command-buffer)
      (unless (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-texify)))))

(defun TeX-texify ()
  "Get everything done."
  (interactive)
  (let ((nextCmd (TeX-command-default (TeX-master-file)))
    proc)
    (if (and (null TeX-texify-Show)
         (equal nextCmd TeX-command-Show))
    (when  (called-interactively-p 'any)
      (message "TeX-texify: Nothing to be done."))
      (TeX-command nextCmd 'TeX-master-file)
      (when (or (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (null (boundp 'TeX-texify-count-same-command))
        (null (boundp 'TeX-texify-last-command))
        (null (equal nextCmd TeX-texify-last-command)))
    (mapc 'make-local-variable '(TeX-texify-sentinel TeX-texify-count-same-command TeX-texify-last-command))
    (setq TeX-texify-count-same-command 1))
      (if (>= TeX-texify-count-same-command TeX-texify-max-runs-same-command)
      (message "TeX-texify: Did %S already %d times. Don't want to do it anymore." TeX-texify-last-command TeX-texify-count-same-command)
    (setq TeX-texify-count-same-command (1+ TeX-texify-count-same-command))
    (setq TeX-texify-last-command nextCmd)
    (and (null (equal nextCmd TeX-command-Show))
         (setq proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
         (setq TeX-texify-sentinel (process-sentinel proc))
         (set-process-sentinel proc 'TeX-texify-sentinel))))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-a") 'TeX-texify)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Barring any specific key sequence (which I know there is one, I just can't *find* it), this will work:

```
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (local-set-key
    (kbd "C-c c")
    (lambda (&optional arg)
      "Run the current document through LaTeX."
      (interactive "p")
      (kmacro-exec-ring-item
       (quote ([3 3 76 97 84 101 88 return] 0 "%d"))
       arg)))
```

This bind the key sequence <kbd>C-c c</kbd> to a keyboard macro that runs <kbd>C-c C-c LaTeX RET</kbd>.

---

If you were wondering, no I didn't make the important part of this myself.  I used <kbd>C-x (</kbd> to start a keyboard macro, then I typed <kbd>C-c C-c LaTeX RET</kbd>, and then <kbd>C-c )</kbd> to finish the macro.  I then used <kbd>C-x C-k n</kbd> to name the macro, and then ran <kbd>M-x insert-kbd-macro</kbd> while inside my `.emacs` (usually findable by <kbd>C-x C-f ~/.emacs</kbd>).

I bind the macro to a key sequence using `local-set-key`, and then add this to the `LaTeX-mode` hook to have it execute every time you enter `LaTeX-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can place the following in your `.emacs` and have everything done automatically in succession, much like Quick Build in TeXMaker.

```lisp
(require 'tex-buf)
(defun TeX-command-default (name)
  "Next TeX command to use. Most of the code is stolen from `TeX-command-query'."
  (cond ((if (string-equal name TeX-region)
                 (TeX-check-files (concat name "." (TeX-output-extension))
                          (list name)
                          TeX-file-extensions)
               (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file)))
             TeX-command-default)
            ((and (memq major-mode '(doctex-mode latex-mode))
                  (TeX-check-files (concat name ".bbl")
                           (mapcar 'car
                               (LaTeX-bibliography-list))
                           BibTeX-file-extensions))
             ;; We should check for bst files here as well.
             TeX-command-BibTeX)
            ((TeX-process-get-variable name
                           'TeX-command-next
                           TeX-command-Show))
            (TeX-command-Show)))


(defcustom TeX-texify-Show t "Start view-command at end of TeX-texify?" :type 'boolean :group 'TeX-command)
(defcustom TeX-texify-max-runs-same-command 5 "Maximal run number of the same command" :type 'integer :group 'TeX-command)

(defun TeX-texify-sentinel (&optional proc sentinel)
  "Non-interactive! Call the standard-sentinel of the current LaTeX-process.
If there is still something left do do start the next latex-command."
  (set-buffer (process-buffer proc))
  (funcall TeX-texify-sentinel proc sentinel)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (when (string-match "\\(finished\\|exited\\)" sentinel)
      (set-buffer TeX-command-buffer)
      (unless (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-texify)))))

(defun TeX-texify ()
  "Get everything done."
  (interactive)
  (let ((nextCmd (TeX-command-default (TeX-master-file)))
    proc)
    (if (and (null TeX-texify-Show)
         (equal nextCmd TeX-command-Show))
    (when  (called-interactively-p 'any)
      (message "TeX-texify: Nothing to be done."))
      (TeX-command nextCmd 'TeX-master-file)
      (when (or (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (null (boundp 'TeX-texify-count-same-command))
        (null (boundp 'TeX-texify-last-command))
        (null (equal nextCmd TeX-texify-last-command)))
    (mapc 'make-local-variable '(TeX-texify-sentinel TeX-texify-count-same-command TeX-texify-last-command))
    (setq TeX-texify-count-same-command 1))
      (if (>= TeX-texify-count-same-command TeX-texify-max-runs-same-command)
      (message "TeX-texify: Did %S already %d times. Don't want to do it anymore." TeX-texify-last-command TeX-texify-count-same-command)
    (setq TeX-texify-count-same-command (1+ TeX-texify-count-same-command))
    (setq TeX-texify-last-command nextCmd)
    (and (null (equal nextCmd TeX-command-Show))
         (setq proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
         (setq TeX-texify-sentinel (process-sentinel proc))
         (set-process-sentinel proc 'TeX-texify-sentinel))))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-a") 'TeX-texify)))
```

This binds the key sequence <kbd>C-c C-a</kbd> to `TeX-texify`, which goes through all of the compilation steps necessary to produce the current document.  Shamelessly stolen from [the Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TN#toc8).